Java won't run the most basic script possible
So I just started learning Java and wrote the most basic script possible in Notepad++:
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Hello, World!");
    }
}

However, even that doesn't work when I run it with javac from the command line. Instead I get the following error message:

I was expecting the code to actually, you know... work. I have no idea what I could be possibly doing wrong at this point. Any suggestions?

javac doesn't run your code, it compiles it. To run the compiled code, use the java command. Better yet, use an IDE like Eclipse or IntelliJ and it will do all that for you.

It's a permissions issue as per the duplicates.

The user you are running as does not have write access to the folder you are in. Possibly It's the + in the file name which is a highly dubious character to use in a file name, but, more likely it's simply access rights.
It is an extremely bad idea to allow just about anybody to write into folders meant for applications you installed. So, however you ended up here, the fact that the Notepad++ folder isn't writable by whatever user you are running javac as, is a good thing. Do not change this!!
Instead, stop using Notepad++ as scratch/project folder. Make a dedicated folder for this and compile there. If you really don't wanna make folders for this, the right place for 'I do not care where this is', is your own folder: C:\Users\yourusername.
